# Will LocalWP staging environment clash with my online site plugins?

Tags: error, testing, plugin

I want to create a staging environment for my site.

I wanted to do it with WPStaging. I read [What is wrong with WP Staging plugin?](https://dessky.com/blog/what-is-wrong-with-wp-staging-plugin/) and some of the problems people were having and I am not sure if I want to go that route. Possibly I want to use LocalWP by Flywheel instead. (Or am I just overreacting?)

My question is - will my plugins clash with those that I have on my live site (woocommence etc.) or because it's local, there is no problem with that?

Also - will my Analytics and Webmaster be screwed up by it, since it will also contain all stuff live web contains?

Thank you!

Comment: Define "clash".

Comment: Basically any kind of issue with plugins on my live site. For example, if I am using woocomence or mailchimp and the settings carry over, will it interfere with their function on live page since they are doubled now?

Comment: If you use something like woocommerce (or any plugin) and you use the same account on both sites and make a transaction on one site, it is obviously going to count as a sale on your account, no matter how many sites it is installed on.  This is why accounts often have a "private key", to keep sites separate and unique.

As for analytics, same thing.  If you are using the same account, then a visit is going to be recorded.  But is this really a problem?  The number of visits while testing on a staging server are unlikely to be significant.